# How to find the cells of a region that intersect a line?

Tags: regions, geometry, computational-geometry, intersection

I'm looking for the fastest way to access the mesh cell (i.e. polygon) in a `Region` that intersects a `Line` in 3D. For example,

```
reg = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[Ball[], PrecisionGoal -> 1, 
   MaxCellMeasure -> 0.1];
Graphics3D[{{Blue, Thick, Line[{{-1, -1, -1}, {0, 0, 0}}]}, 
  Opacity[0.8], reg}, Axes -> True]
```

[image]

Here's a slow naive way:

```
ps = MeshPrimitives[reg, 2];
intersections = 
  If[EmptyRegion[3] =!= 
      RegionIntersection[#, Line[{{0, 0, 0}, {-1, -1, -1}}]], #, 
     Nothing] & /@ ps;
Graphics3D[{{Red, Line[{{0, 0, 0}, {-1, -1, -1}}]}, intersections}, 
 Axes -> True]
```

[image]

There must be an easy efficient way to find the cell that intersects the line, I'm just not seeing it.

Comment: What version are you using?, my 11.3 says that BDR is not a graphics3d primitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before I begin, I'd like to say that this is indeed something that I really miss in Mathematica 11.3.

Well, we can try to employ `RegionDistance` to find the intersection point as follows:

```
R = DiscretizeRegion[Sphere[], MaxCellMeasure -> {1 -> 0.5}];
L = Line[{{0, 0, 0}, {-1, -1, -1}}];

d = RegionDistance[R];
curve = (1 - t) L[[1, 1]] + t L[[1, 2]];
pt = curve /. FindRoot[d[curve] == 0, {t, 0, 1}, Method -> "Secant"]
```

> {-0.576338, -0.576338, -0.576338}

For more than one intersection, one may use the good ol' `MeshFunction` approach:

```
gc = Cases[
   Plot[d[curve], {t, 0, 1}, MeshFunctions -> {#2 &}, 
    Mesh -> {{0.01}}, MeshStyle -> Red],
   _GraphicsComplex,
   ∞
   ];
candidates = Join[{0.}, Sort[gc[[1, 1, Cases[gc, _Point, ∞][[1, 1]], 1]]], {1.}];
pts = curve /. FindRoot[
 d[curve] == 0, 
 {t, #[[1]], #[[2]]}, 
 Method -> "Secant"] & /@ Partition[candidates, 2, 1];
```

This returns only the intersection points, not the intersected triangles. 
But the cell indices of the nearest mesh cells of highest dimension(?) can be obtained by

```
intersectedtriangles = DeleteDuplicates[Region`Mesh`MeshNearestCellIndex[R, pts]]
```

> {{2, 744}}

```
Graphics3D[{Thick, L, MeshPrimitives[R, intersectedtriangles]}]
```

[image]

Comment: @ HenrikSchumacher Very helpful! Where could I find further documentation  to `Region`Mesh`MeshNearestCellIndex`? Thanks.

Comment: @Ulrich As always with these undocumented functions such as ``Region`Mesh`MeshNearestCellIndex``: Nowhere. Unfortunately. =/

Comment: It's a pity, thanks

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I'm seeing `Part::partw: Part 3 of {Identity,Identity} does not exist.` warning in your call to Cases

Comment: @M.R. Sorry, I cannot reproduce this. =/   But admittedly, the way I used `MeshFunctions` is not very robust. If `Plot` finds no intersections, the rest of the code will throw errors.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher what if I only needed the normal of the intersection point, not the intercepting cell - is there a faster way?

Comment: @M.R. Hm. I don't think so...

Comment: Why did you choose not to use `RegionIntersection` by the way? @HenrikSchumacher

Comment: Because `RegionIntersection` can currently intersect only regions of the _same_ embedding dimension. And I tried to use only methods that  have complexity $O(\log(N))$ where $N$ is the number of triangles.

Comment: Nice, why not replace the line with a very thin polygon then?

Comment: I tried. But `RegionIntersection` wants `MeshRegion`s as input and nearly gegenerate triangles are eliminated  when initializing a `MeshRegion`...